# Has anyone done a GCTA of leg length?

Tags: genetics

There is extensive genomic research on height, but nobody seems to have done a gcta of leg length.

Comment: What do you mean by "doing GCTA of leg length"?

Comment: Do you mean "do we know the [QTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_trait_locus) for leg length?"

Comment: I don't and only few people visited this post yet, so saying "nobody" sounds a bit extreme. I googled the thing a few times and found [Genome-Wide Complex Trait Analysis](http://cnsgenomics.com/software/gcta/). It seems to be a recent technic that has been only used a few times only and it seems to always be about height. There is therefore probably nothing on leg length. Seems not surprising if I (and others) don't know its meaning.

Comment: If a concept is likely to not be understood, please link to its definition (or even better, include a definition) and indicate what does the abbreviation stand for. I let you make the edit. Thanks.

Comment: I am a PhD candidate in population genetics and I find your comment (now deleted) offensive :) You should just add a link and definition to save everyone's time.

Comment: Voting to close as "homework" because it's extremely trivial: a Google scholar search is the service you need for this. You could also look at the articles citing the original methods paper. As far as I know there's nothing published specific to leg length (and I doubt it will happen soon - it's a fairly uninteresting thing to measure).

Comment: GCTA is not a well known term. I myself have worked a bit on genomics but I was not aware. Providing context and explanation is not only important for explaining your question but is also useful for users who refer to the post to learn some facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to the use of the software [GTCA](http://cnsgenomics.com/software/gcta/) (which stands for Genome-Wide Complex Trait Analysis). Original paper: [Yang et al. (2011)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21167468).

I looked to the papers who cited Yang et al. (2011) and quickly scanned through looking for "leg". I did not find anything on it. So my best guess is: No, nobody ever applied GTCA to leg length.